# Cashing my economic impact payment

Tags: check, cash

I currently have no ID.  I went to the DMV yesterday with my birth certificate, social security card, and prof of residence to get a state issued ID and they rudely informed me that they are not currently issuing IDs and when I asked her what I could do to get my money she quickly told me to leave that they couldn't help me.  I have also tried using my paypal app to cash it but Ingo money services that they use cannot verify my identity to allow me to use it.  I even wrote a letter to governor Tate Reeves but have yet to hear anything back.    I really need my money to pay my light bill before the no cut off order is lifted and I am without power or money.. Please help me. What do I do? I fo currently have an old college ID, birth certificate, ss card and proof of residence but I CAN'T FIND a check cashing place that will help me...???